# what is the use of @html.partial("_somepage") in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

what is the usage of`@html.partial("_somepage")` in mvc Framework

It is used for code reusage or some other

Comment: Check this http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/2IKW160912-Partial-View-in-Asp.net-MVC3-Razor.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are given this format it takes like a link to another page or another link.partial view majorly used for renduring the html files from one place to another.

`Html.RenderPartial()` is a void method - you can check whether a method is a void method by placing your mouse over the call to RenderPartial in your code and you will see the text (extension) void HtmlHelper.RenderPartial...

Void methods require a semicolon at the end of the calling code.

In the Webforms view engine you would have encased your `Html.RenderPartial()` call within the bee stings `<% %>`

like so

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("Path/to/my/partial/view"); %>
```

when you are using the Razor view engine the equivalent is

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("Path/to/my/partial/view");}
```

Answer (score 1):

"If you want to reuse a view in your web application, you can go for the partial view concept..."

[Partial View in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-4)